# Ionic Phonegap Cordova: cheapest Mac model to build for iOS?

Tags: macos, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, hybrid

I need to buy a Mac just for building ionic/phonegap/cordova hybrid apps. 
Which model is good enough for the task?
Want to spend as little as possible and I don't mind if it is slow.

Comment: Why dont you rent a mac in cloud then? Check out this link - http://www.macincloud.com/

Comment: That's a great idea Gandhi. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Posted the answer. You may accept if it helps so that it will be helpful for others too. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best idea would be to rent a mac rather that purchasing it just for the sake of building hybrid apps. You can consider [MacInCloud](http://www.macincloud.com/) option which may work out cheap for you.

Comment: [Mac Stadium](https://macstadium.com/) is also good for this, but a used or refurb Mac Mini may work out cheaper.  I'm still developing on a 2010 Mac Mini that I retrofitted 16Gb RAM to and it's still acceptable and runs the latest Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better (cheaper) solutions for you,

1. Use adobe phone gap build? [build.phonegap.com/](http://build.phonegap.com/)
   it is very powerful, just upload your code in zip file and it will do all the stuff for you, i have been using for a while, and it allows you to have free unlimited builds for one app.
2. Use the ionic native build service, i felt that phoneGap build is easier and better, however, ionic native build allow you to have 30 native builds per month. http://docs.ionic.io/docs/package-ios

For sure these will work using windows or Linux, but you still need to create the build certificates to use these services, and to do so you need a mac, 
So for me i have used a virtual machine copy of (OSX) to create the certificates on windows, or you can borrow a friends mac to do that :) .

Comment: If you're writing your own plugins or need bleeding edge Cordova, PhoneGap Build probably isn't for you but if you're doing something with off the shelf plugins then go for it.